# String.split() using multiple character delimeter

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a String saved in the database like this:

```
01/01/2014$%^&02/01/2014
```

I am using the `split()` java method. Here is my code:

```
String value = database.getValue(); // this returns the value mentioned above
String values[] = value.split("$%^&");

System.out.println("length is = " + values.length);
System.out.println(values[0]);
```

**The Output:**

```
length is = 1
01/01/2014$%^&02/01/2014
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: use Escape sequence("\\") between your delimiter

Comment: `^` and `$` are metacharacters; escape those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String values[] = value.split(Pattern.quote("$%^&"));
```

> What am I doing wrong?

[`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regex as its argument. Some characters in your String have [special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html). In your case, you want the String representation, not regex. `quote` does that for you.

Alternative solutions:

- Escape the special characters by `\\` (Escaping regex is done by `\`. But in Java, `\` is written `\\`)
- Use [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) that accepts String

Comment: Or escape special characters :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too. Here we can escape special characters.

```
    String value = "01/01/2014$%^&02/01/2014";
    String values[] = value.split("\\$%\\^&");

    System.out.println("length is = " + values.length);
    System.out.println(values[0]);
```

Out put:

```
   length is = 2
   01/01/2014
```

Comment: I can't use escape because the splitter is saved in the database too as is.

Comment: @Shahe then you can use `ᴍaroun ᴍaroun`s way